# GS base added up with offset does not correspond to gs:offset

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, x86-64, qemu

When debugging Linux Kernel ran as QEMU guest with `GDB` I faced the following instruction:

```
mov    rcx,QWORD PTR gs:0x1fbc0
```

The question is the `rcx` register does contain the `gs` base added up with the value `0x1fbc0`. Here is what I figured out in gdb:

```
#Before execution of the instruction
(gdb) p/x $rcx
$10 = 0x0
(gdb) p/x $gs_base
$11 = 0xffff888237c80000

#Execution of the instruction
(gdb) si
vm_unmapped_area (info=info@entry=0xffffc90000eb7d70) at mm/mmap.c:2002

#Completely unclear value
(gdb) p/x $rcx
$12 = 0xffff888105e79980
```

My first thought was that `GDB` reported the GS base incorrectly, but then I got the same from the `rdmsr` tool

```
$ sudo rdmsr -p 2 0xc0000101
ffff888237c80000
```

Making things even more unclear.

**Why doesn't `gs:0x1fbc0` result in `$gs_base` + `0x1fbc0`?**

Comment: `mov` with a memory source **loads data** from the linear address indicated by `$gs_base` + `0x1fbc0`, it does not load the linear address itself into the destination.

Comment: @ecm I thought to load from the memory address pointed to by `gs:0x1fbc0` it should be enclosed with brackets as `[gs:0x1fbc0]`.

Comment: @ecm Oh, really. Just checked it

Comment: @ecm thank you very much for your comment. If you post it as an answer I would accept it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mov` with a memory source **loads data** from the linear address indicated by `$gs_base` + `0x1fbc0`, it does not load the linear address itself into the destination.

To address some of your further comments, the `qword ptr` keywords for a MASM-style dialect indicate a memory access rather than loading an immediate. The rule that all memory accesses are wrapped in brackets `[...]` and everything else (immediate or register accesses) is not wrapped in brackets is a NASM-ism. In MASM a destination can have keywords `{size} ptr` or brackets `[...]` or just specify a variable name to indicate to the assembler to use a memory load. Absent any of those, or by specifying a variable name with an `offset` keyword prepended, it will encode so as to load an immediate number instead.

Even if your example was an immediate load it would just be `mov rcx, 0x1fbc0` without `gs` as there is no immediate-to-register form instructions that include segment override prefixes with any effect whatsoever. You can technically put a `gs` prefix in front of such an instruction and it will generally still be decoded fine in practice. However, the `gs` prefix would serve no purpose then. A disassembler (like gdb's) would hopefully not display the source immediate operand of such an instruction with a `gs:` prefix.

Comment: Note that even `lea rcx, QWORD PTR gs:0x1fbc0` will still just give you `0x1fbc0`.  The "effective address" in an address calculation is the `base + idx*scale +disp` part that becomes the offset of a seg:off logical address, and that's what LEA loads.  (So you can use it for address math to compute offsets, where you don't want a non-zero DS or SS base added.)  There's no way (without special instructions like `rdmsr` or `rdgsbase`) to access the segment base.